# How can I get letters by searching two different volume names at the same time？

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

I konw how to get letters by searching volume names.
Like this
`wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName="xxx" get DeviceID`

But I have two volume names. So I need the command performed like this

`wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName="xxx" or VolumeName="aaa" get DeviceID`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `for %i in (aaa xxx) do wmic logicaldisk where volumename="%i" get DeviceID /value`

Comment: Why is there the requirement to get both at the same time? Why is it not possible to run the command `wmic` two times? What about `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID,VolumeName | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"VolumeName1" /C:"VolumeName2"` to get output the list of all devices identifiers and volume names and filter next the output on the two volume names of interest?

Comment: Because I use it in Node.js. So I need a easy output to handle.@Mofi

Comment: You know that solution provided by Gerhard runs `wmic` two times, aren't you? The solution to run `wmic` just once for two volume names is `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where 'VolumeName="VolumeName1" or VolumeName="VolumeName2"' GET DeviceID`. But I would suggest to append `,VolumeName` as otherwise it would not be possible to find out which drive letter is for which volume. `wmic` compares the volume names case-insensitive.

Comment: For completeness: It is also possible to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where (VolumeName="VolumeName1" or VolumeName="VolumeName2") GET DeviceID,VolumeName` with `(` and `)` instead of `'`. See the Microsoft documentations about [WHERE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/where-clause) and [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) as used for this task.

Comment: @Mofi, you are correct, it will run `wmic` twice, I just posted that as an example to OP if he planned on using metavariables in other commands.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks! Your answer give me a nice output that simple to handle!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to use the metavariables. As per my initial example, the `wmic` command is executed twice, as mentioned by **@Mofi**.

if you want to use the output as variables in another command, like some tool within `node.js`, you can run the command once, but search for either volume using `Findstr`'s regular expression:

```
for /f %i in ('wmic logicaldisk get deviceid^, volumename ^| findstr /I /R "\<volume 1\> \<Volume 2\>"') do echo %i
```

if it is not your intention to use the output as variables in other commands, then eliminate the for loop entirely, you can then just run the command as specified in the last comment by **@Mofi**

Comment: oh, and obviously double the `%` on the metavariables, if used in a batch file. So change `%i` to `%%i`